# Is there a way to get the index of an element and store it to update an XPATH in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have a list that looks like this in my UI:
[UI image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ts6G0.png)

The XPATH for the first row's "..." button is `//tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a[1]/i[1]`, and each subsequent row's XPATH has the `tr[]` portion updated depending on the index of the row.

Is it possible to store the xpath of the button as:
`button =  //tbody/tr[i]/td[2]/a[1]/i[1]` ?

And if so, if I create a new rule, is there a way I can update `tr[i]` to reflect the index of the newly added rule so I can call `button.click()`?

Comment: Can you share the HTML source ?

Answer (score 0):

looks like, you wanna make indexing bit dynamic  :

so, for this **xpath** :-

```
//tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a[1]/i[1]
```

you can do following:

```
i = 1
button = f"//tbody/tr[{i}]/td[2]/a[1]/i[1]"
```

and can use it in Selenium.

you can use it for loop as well with the indices.